# Using Angular Router to route to application on a different port

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two applications, one running on port 4200 and another running on port 8181. I need to access resources on port 8181 from port 4200.

The application on port 4200 wants to redirect to a url of this form:

```
/fv/#/fv/am
```

But this path does not exist on the application on port 4200, but at 8100. So the application at port 4200 tries to redirect to:

```
http://localhost:4200/fv/#/fv/am
```

when what I need is for it to redirect to

```
http://localhost:8100/fv/#/fv/am
```

I've tried changing the proxy configuration, but that does not work, as I still get redirected to port 4200.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Router is for navigation within and single page application. To go to `http://localhost:8100/fv/#/fv/am` would be booting another application so it needs to be an external navigation. You can't use the Router for external navigation. Replace `<a [routerLink]` directive with `<a href="http://localhost:8100/fv/#/fv/am"` or `this.router.navigate(http://localhost:8100/fv/#/fv/am)` with `windows.location = http://localhost:8100/fv/#/fv/am`.

Note: Its not clear what is doing the redirect. You might get better answers if you include a code example.